# Html response object has not attribute text

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "crawl"
    start_urls = [url]

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
        print soup.prettify()
```

I have this chunck of code. I'm using scrapy and when I execute it I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/vagrant_data/cars_scraper/cars_scraper/spiders/__init__.py", line 17, in parse
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Response.body`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.body) attribute instead of `text`.